# How to extract phone number and name from a string using vba on Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Am new to VBA, took the course a long time ago. With the aid of a friend, we put together  a code that removes country code from phone number, leaving just the actual phone number. 
Now i want to include name to the extracted phone number i.e if i input  "John Luke +447895432123" without the quote in a cell, it just displays "John Luke 7895432123" in the excel cell..

Not sure if its clear enough, wish i could send someone the entire file to look at, i will really appreciate.

```
Sub Runner()

Dim i As Long, k As Long
Dim lpage As Long

lpage = Sheet2.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row


For i = lpage To 8 Step -1
If InStr(1, i / 500, ".") = 0 Then
        DoEvents
End If

For k = 2 To Sheet2.Range("lak1").End(xlToLeft).Column

If Sheet2.Cells(i, k) <> "" Then

    Sheet2.Cells(i, k) = Extract_Number_from_string(Sheet2.Cells(i, k))
    If Left(Sheet2.Cells(i, k), 2) <> 44 And Left(Sheet2.Cells(i, k), 1) <> "7" Then
        Sheet2.Cells(i, k) = ""
    ElseIf Left(Sheet2.Cells(i, k), 2) = 44 Then ' And Left(Sheet2.Cells(i, k), 1) <> "7" Then
        Sheet2.Cells(i, k) = Right(Sheet2.Cells(i, k), Len(Sheet2.Cells(i, k)) - 2)

    End If


End If

Next k

Next i

'duplicate delete



For k = 2 To Sheet2.Range("lak1").End(xlToLeft).Column

On Error Resume Next
Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(8, k), Sheet2.Cells(900000, k)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
On Error Resume Next
  Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(8, k), Sheet2.Cells(900000, k)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next k

End Sub



Sub RunnerRemTab()

Dim i As Long, k As Long
Dim lpage As Long

lpage = Sheet1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row


For i = lpage To 8 Step -1
If InStr(1, i / 500, ".") = 0 Then
        DoEvents
End If

For k = 2 To Sheet1.Range("lak1").End(xlToLeft).Column

If Sheet1.Cells(i, k) <> "" Then

    Sheet1.Cells(i, k) = Extract_Number_from_string(Sheet1.Cells(i, k))
    If Left(Sheet1.Cells(i, k), 2) <> 44 And Left(Sheet1.Cells(i, k), 1) <> "7" Then
        Sheet1.Cells(i, k) = ""
    ElseIf Left(Sheet1.Cells(i, k), 2) = 44 Then ' And Left(Sheet1.Cells(i, k), 1) <> "7" Then
        Sheet1.Cells(i, k) = Right(Sheet1.Cells(i, k), Len(Sheet1.Cells(i, k)) - 2)

    End If


End If

Next k

Next i

'duplicate delete
For k = 2 To Sheet1.Range("lak1").End(xlToLeft).Column

On Error Resume Next
Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(8, k), Sheet1.Cells(900000, k)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
On Error Resume Next
  Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(8, k), Sheet1.Cells(900000, k)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next k

End Sub
```

Right now, the phone number extraction works just fine, the issue is including the name to the phone number, and i've tried every method i could thing of to the extent i can't even retrace my steps back,

Comment: If you can provide a handful of sample entries that I can work on to simulate the result, that would be great before this attracted 3 more close votes. And I think we can go with formulas too if the sample entries are not that complicated.

Comment: Ok.. but then, i could forward you the excel sheet through a medium of your choice like email.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Position As Long
    Dim strWholeText As String, strName As String, strPhoneNo As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        strWholeText = .Range("A1").Value

        Position = InStr(1, strWholeText, "+")

        If Position > 0 Then
            strName = Left(strWholeText, Position - 2)
            strPhoneNo = Mid(strWholeText, Position + 3, (Len(strWholeText) - (Position + 2)))
            Debug.Print strName
            Debug.Print strPhoneNo
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```